# Subtracting values from two different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
Meetingyear1
+----+----------+------------+
| id | county   | attendance |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | Nyeri    |        100 |
|  2 | Murang'a |         50 |
|  3 | Kiambu   |        200 |
|  4 | Nairobi  |         50 |
|  5 | Kisumu   |        300 |
|  6 | Nyeri    |         50 |
|  7 | Kisumu   |        400 |
|  8 | Nairobi  |        800 |
|  9 | Kiambu   |         80 |
| 10 | Murang'a |        200 |
+----+----------+------------+

Meetingyear2
+----+----------+------------+
| id | county   | attendance |
+----+----------+------------+
|  1 | Nyeri    |         50 |
|  2 | Murang'a |         78 |
|  3 | Kiambu   |        500 |
|  4 | Nairobi  |       1000 |
|  5 | Kisumu   |          0 |
|  6 | Nyeri    |         12 |
|  7 | Kisumu   |        200 |
|  8 | Nairobi  |         60 |
|  9 | Kiambu   |        100 |
| 10 | Murang'a |          0 |
+----+----------+------------+



select meetingyear1.county,sum(meetingyear1.attendance) as attendance1,sum(meetingyear2.attendance) as attendance2,sum(meetingyear1.attendance-meetingyear2.attendance) as difference from meetingyear1 INNER JOIN meetingyear2 ON meetingyear1.county =meetingyear2.county GROUP BY county;
```

Am getting this

```
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| county   | attendance1 | attendance2 | difference |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
| Kiambu   |         560 |        1200 |       -640 |
| Kisumu   |        1400 |         400 |       1000 |
| Murang'a |         500 |         156 |        344 |
| Nairobi  |        1700 |        2120 |       -420 |
| Nyeri    |         300 |         124 |        176 |
+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+
```

expected result is

```
COUNTY         ATTENDANCE
NYERI            88
MURANG'A         172
KIAMBU           320
NAIROBI          210
KISUMU           500
```

Comment: What you want exactly bcz you query not match with expected result.. Mention your tried query

Comment: I want to subtract values  meetingyear1 AND meetingyear2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `UNION` the two tables together, separating the attendance into two columns (one for each year), and you can then `SUM` the results by `county`:

```
SELECT county, SUM(year1) AS attendance1, SUM(year2) AS attendance2, SUM(year1) - SUM(year2) AS difference
FROM (SELECT id, county, attendance AS year1, 0 AS year2
      FROM meetingyear1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, county, 0 AS year1, attendance AS year2
      FROM meetingyear2) a
GROUP BY county
ORDER BY difference
```

Output:

```
county      attendance1     attendance2     difference
Kiambu      280             600             -320
Nairobi     850             1060            -210
Nyeri       150             62              88
Murang'a    250             78              172
Kisumu      700             200             500
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=69fc4555425fba3961a3b6aad065d9ad)

Comment: what if Iwant to ADD more columns in both tables with values to be subtracted

Comment: thats why I did ask you

Comment: I have a table as above but I want to increase the number of Colums to attendance2,attendance3 but when I try using  SELECT county, SUM(year1) AS attendance1, SUM(year2) AS attendance2, SUM(year1) - SUM(year2) AS difference
    -> FROM (SELECT id, county, attendance AS year1, 0 AS year2
    ->       FROM meetingyear1
    ->       UNION ALL
    ->       SELECT id, county, 0 AS year1, attendance AS year2
    ->       FROM meetingyear2) a
    -> GROUP BY county
    -> ;am getting 0;

Comment: @AnthonyMwangi see my updated demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=534407e8f5bce2b15a22ac4f4719fa6c) I think it does what you want

Comment: @AnthonyMwangi note that if you want the differences to be positive, just replace `SUM(year1) - SUM(year2)` with `ABS(SUM(year1) - SUM(year2))`

Comment: It worked there were some typos in my side. It worked propery I even upvoted it

Answer (score 0):

You can try below - using subquery and join

```
select A.county, attendance1-attendance2 as difference from
(
select meetingyear1.county, sum(meetingyear1.attendance) as attendance1
from meetingyear1
group by meetingyear1.county
)A inner join
(
select meetingyear2.county, sum(meetingyear2.attendance) as attendance2
from meetingyear2
group by meetingyear2.county
)B on A.county=B.county
```

Comment: This will only work if the same counties are in both tables

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT county, CASE WHEN diff_ < 0 THEN diff_ * -1 ELSE diff_ END AS diff_
FROM(
select m1.county, SUM(m1.attendance) - (SELECT SUM(m2.attendance) FROM Meetingyear2 m2 WHERE m1.county = m2.county) diff_
from Meetingyear1 m1
GROUP BY m1.county
)T
ORDER BY diff_
```